# How to use this module with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, kraken.js

I have this module that has been generated by a grunt process:

```
require = (function e(t, n, r) {
    function s(o, u) {
        if (!n[o]) {
            if (!t[o]) {
                var a = typeof require == "function" && require;
                if (!u && a) return a(o, !0);
                if (i) return i(o, !0);
                var f = new Error("Cannot find module '" + o + "'");
                throw f.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", f
            }
            var l = n[o] = {
                exports: {}
            };
            t[o][0].call(l.exports, function(e) {
                var n = t[o][1][e];
                return s(n ? n : e)
            }, l, l.exports, e, t, n, r)
        }
        return n[o].exports
    }
    var i = typeof require == "function" && require;
    for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++) s(r[o]);
    return s
})({
    "_languagepack": [function(require, module, exports) {
        module.exports = {
            "en-US": {
                "errors/404.properties": {
                    "header": "File not found",
                    "description": "The URL <code>{url}</code> did not resolve to a route."
                },
                "errors/500.properties": {
                    "header": "Internal server error",
                    "description": "The URL <code>{url}</code> had the following error <code>{err}</code>."
                },
                "errors/503.properties": {
                    "header": "Service unavailable",
                    "description": "The service is unavailable. Please try back shortly."
                },
                "index.properties": {
                    "greeting": "Hello, {name}!"
                },
                "layouts/master.properties": {
                    "greeting": "Hello, {name}!"
                },
                "partial-usecontent.properties": {
                    "greeting": "Usecontent, {name}!"
                },
                "partial.properties": {
                    "greeting": "Partial, {name}!"
                }
            }
        }
    }, {}]
}, {}, []);
```

This module should be used to access to localized content , this file is specific to locale "en-US". How should I use browserify to access for example to the object *"errors/404.properties"* ?

I have tried to require the module as `var enUS= require(../module.js)` but this results in an empty object `{}`

Comment: Do you need to create different js files for different languages? Maybe some browserify transformation helps you. (Example: https://github.com/tableflip/i18n-browserify)

Comment: @KirillErmolov I'm already using a [grunt task](https://github.com/krakenjs/grunt-makara-browserify) who makes different js files according to the language. The one I have posted is the one for en-US locale, now I'm trying to access to the data that this js exports, but I can't find the right way to do it (I'm a browserify noob)